# Как написать рецепт на создание новой папки и файла cookbooks Chef Vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, vagrant

Мне надо создать папку `www` и файл `index.php`, на виртуальной машине.

Путь до папки `/var/www/index.php`

Как будет выглядеть рецепт cookbooks? Использую образ ubuntu 14.04

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать папку

```
directory '/var/www' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

создать файл

```
file '/var/www/index.php' do
  content '<html>Hello. World!!!</html>'
  mode '0755'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
end
```